# Azure API Management - named value at API scope

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am wondering whether it is possible to specify something like `Named value` but for each API separately?

So if I have, say `foo-API` and `bar-API` I can specify for each a *named value-like variable*, eg `my-url`. So now when I create a global policy

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <send-request mode="new">
            <set-url>{{my-url}}</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-body>something</set-body>
        </send-request>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

but `send-request` will send request to the API specific URL (eg. different URL for DEV, TEST, PROD)

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here, but send a separate request on each API call? If it's a global policy you may want to look at the context like ´context.Product.Name´  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Named values are a global collection, the only workaround is to name them to be descriptive enough, i.e. prefix with API id.